# Valores distintos

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT `forma`,`id_produto`,`id_lanche`,`qtd_max`, 
       if(`id_lanche` in (select `id_lanche` from `produtos` 
            where `id_lanche` = {$id_produto}),'checked','') as marca FROM `formas`
```

db produto = produtos

db receita = formas

Este código faz o seguinte trabalho: Busca no db o `id` do produto e a receita que é.
E marca os ingredientes e sua quantidade.

```
id     nome      id_lanche    preço
1     X-egg       1            7.00
2     X-tudo      2            9.00

tabela receita
id    id_produto  id_lanche    preço     quantidade (quantiodade no caso e quanto o produto tem de cada item)
1     1           1            1.00      1
2     2           1            2.00      2
3     3           1            2.00      2
4     4           1            3.00      1
5     1           2            1.00      1
6     2           2            2.00      2
7     5           2            2.00      1
8     4           2            3.00      1



Alface         [X] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x
Bacon          [ ] 1x  [X] 2x  [ ] 3x
Queijo Cheddar [ ] 1x  [X] 2x  [ ] 3x
Mostarda dijon [X] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x
bife           [ ] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x
pão            [ ] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x
Alface         [ ] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x
Bacon          [ ] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x
```

Agora preciso que ele também elimine os elementos duplicados... Mas observando se ele esta marcado ou não... Eu coloquei um `group by` formas. Mas ele não distingue se esta marcado ou não.

Comment: No caso a tabela `formas` é a primeira ali?

Comment: a tabela formas e a tabela receita

Comment: O que é a representação daquelas marcações ali `Alface         [X] 1x  [ ] 2x  [ ] 3x`? Se possível coloque o resultado da sua consulta.

Comment: por essa cunsulta fala que o id_lanche 1 tem a forma (receita) do id_lanche nesse caso sao 4 itens ai ver qual a quantidade de cada item e marca o checkbox correspondente a quantidade

Comment: so que o problema e que ele ta imprimindo 2 alface pq tem 2 alfaces no db e ele tem que imprimir apenas um alface... mas observando e dando prioridade para o que esta marcado e eliminando o que nao esta marcado.. caso nao esteja nem um item marcado ele imprime qualquer um

Comment: Certo, você tem que fazer uma pergunta de cada vêz, na pergunta você está misturando a consulta SQL com a lógica de impressão, daí fica difícil pra gente te ajudar a identificar o problema.

Comment: 1º Qual o motivo de ter 2 alfaces no banco? 2º Coloque o resultado da sua consulta (a mesma que você colocou na pergunta). 3º Coloque também uma representação da tabela produtos.

Comment: tem 2 alfaces pq tem o id_lanche da tabela forma, ela confere com o id_lanche lanche da tabela produto... e monta a receita... e tem a quantidade do item

Comment: @KaduAmaral, pronto editei o post... ta imprimindo como se fosse o produto 1 x-egg

Comment: Veja se consegue simular o problema aqui [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), cria uma simulação dos seus dados e tabelas e consulta.

Comment: Um simples union de formas com produtos e contar a quantidade de produtos não seria mais simples !?

Comment: mais tem o que e marcado

Answer (score 0):

Desta forma não funciona?

```
SELECT `forma`,`id_produto`,`id_lanche`,`qtd_max`, 
       if(`id_lanche` in (select `id_lanche` from `produtos` 
            where `id_lanche` = {$id_produto}),'checked','') as marca FROM `formas`
group by `forma`,`id_produto`,`id_lanche`,`qtd_max`, 
       if(`id_lanche` in (select `id_lanche` from `produtos` 
            where `id_lanche` = {$id_produto}),'checked','');
```

Comment: ele apenas organizo a busca por ordem alfabetica... ainda imprime 2 alface

Comment: ele tem que identificar qual alface ta marcado e qual não esta... o que não estiver ele elimina... caso nao tenha nem um marcado ele ponhe qualquer um... mais todos valores distintos